# How to encrypt a JSON payload in Faraday (Rails 5)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, faraday

I'm a little new to Rails and using the Faraday gem for API calls so please be gentle. :)

We use Faraday (gem) for all our server-originated API calls in our Rails application. One of the external services that we use requires us to encrypt all our payloads using an RSA 4096 public key provided by the service provider.

Typically the way we use Faraday is:

```
connection = Faraday.new(:url: url) do |faraday|
    faraday.request :url_encoded
    faraday.response :logger       
    faraday.adapter  Faraday.default_adapter  
end

parameters = '{
    "key1": "value1"
    "key2":XXXXXX,
    .
    .

}'

response = connection.post do |req|
    req.url some_url
    req.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
    req.body = <encrypted JSON parameters given in **parameters**>
end
```

I wanted to know if we could directly encrypt the *parameters* object has after converting it to JSON, and passing it in the **req.body** attribute, or if there is a more systematic way to do the same.

Thanks a lot in advance for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, why not? I might be missing something.

You can encrypt any String and pass it along through the body of a request. However, if you do so, you probably want to stay within proper content types as per your application/json header.

JSON:

```
{ 
     name: "Alice", 
     age: 25 
}
```

We could encrypt each individual key-value pair:

```
{ 
     name: gtLHeq+OR9JDvAlTFN98VZlqCrrRvFITw5TnFwGHCB0+8=, 
     age: gt9gI3dSssl5BOcSpYr0egkye98VZlqCrrRvFITw5TnFwGHCB0+8= 
}
```

Or we could encrypt the whole JSON block:

```
{ 
     secret: W29Ud80egkye98VZlqCrrRvFITw5TnFwGHCB0+8= 
}
```

I wrapped the encrypted JSON in more JSON so that we didn't break the content-type. But I'm not sure if your 3rd party service is equipped to decrypt the whole block or if it looks for specific key-value pairs in the JSON and decrypts those. That's the important distinction. You can encrypt almost anything and ship it over the wire, but if the listener isn't conditioned to decrypt your data in that format, you're forced to conform to their format.

Comment: Yes, this works! Turns out the error I was getting was because of using the wrong encryption key and not because of anything to do with Faraday. Thanks for your time!